# How can I manually create a method that will convert a decimal to other bases in Java?

Tags: java, math, methods, decimal, jgrasp

I have a professor that does not allow me to use the easy method to convert a decimal to other bases (binary, hex, and octal). I have to create my own method to do so.

```
public static String base(int num, int base)
{
  String output = "";

  while (num != 0)
  {
     int value = num % base;
     output = getDigit(value) + output;
     num = num / base;
  }
  return output;
}

public static char getDigit(char n)
{
  {
     switch (n)
     {
        case 0: return '0';
        case 1: return '1';
        case 2: return '2';
        case 3: return '3';
        case 4: return '4';
        case 5: return '5';
        case 6: return '6';
        case 7: return '7';
        case 8: return '8';
        case 9: return '9';
        case 10: return 'A';
        case 11: return 'B';
        case 12: return 'C';
        case 13: return 'D';
        case 14: return 'E';
        case 15: return 'F';
        default:
        System.out.println("Wrong key inputted!");
     }

  }
  return n;
```

Note that I have made a lot of mistake.
I have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: Obviously, you're doing dec to hex, but what's not so obvious is the question of what your specific difficulties seem to be. Your professor is trying to train you to think properly, so think about this: "If I were to ask a stranger for help, what information would I need to provide in order to obtain that help?" Check out the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: Are you using an IDE? If so, it should have pointed out the data-type mis-match. If not, you should start using one, like Eclipse.

Comment: Your `getDigit` logic can be improved - something like `return n < 10 ? '0' + n : 'A' + n - 10;` would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Java's Integer class has built-in functions to return the Strings, for hex [toHexString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29), for binary [toBinaryString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) and for octal [toOctalString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toOctalString%28int%29). Hope this helps..

**UPDATE**

Your logic is correct and working, however there were few errors in the code, have a look:

```
public class Convert {
    public static String base(int num, int base)
    {
        String output = "";

        while (num != 0)
        {
            int value = num % base;
            output = Convert.getDigit(value) + output;
            num = num / base;
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static char getDigit(int n)
    {

         switch (n)
         {
             case 0: return '0';
             case 1: return '1';
             case 2: return '2';
             case 3: return '3';
             case 4: return '4';
             case 5: return '5';
             case 6: return '6';
             case 7: return '7';
             case 8: return '8';
             case 9: return '9';
             case 10: return 'A';
             case 11: return 'B';
             case 12: return 'C';
             case 13: return 'D';
             case 14: return 'E';
             case 15: return 'F';
             default:
                 System.out.println("Wrong key inputted!");
         }
         return ' ';
    }

    public static void main(String ...args){
        System.out.println(Convert.base(Integer.parseInt(args[0]),Integer.parseInt(args[1])));
    }
}
```

Comment: the original poster specifically stated "I have a professor that does not allow me to use the easy method to convert a decimal to other bases..." Your solution seems like one of those "easy method(s)," given that the professor appears to be trying to teach a lesson about implementing algorithms.

Comment: I skipped a few words here and there... :P